# yard 0.7.3 fails to build my README in both markdown and textile

Tags: ruby, markdown, textile, yard

I've decided to convert the README file in a project of mine to markdown and have been using yard verify the documentation rendered out ok.  So I installed rdiscount, changed README to README.md and tried:

```
yard doc README.md
```

which gave me a waring:

```
[warn]: Syntax error in `readme.md`:(3,18): syntax error, unexpected tinteger, expecting $end
```

So I tried:

```
yard doc -m markdown -- README.md
```

Same problem.  Running:

```
yard doc --backtrace -- README.md
```

gives a little bit more info:

```
[warn]: Syntax error in `readme.md`:(3,18): syntax error, unexpected tinteger, expecting $end
[error]: ParserSyntaxError: syntax error in `README.md`:(3,18): syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting $end
[error]: Stack trace:
    /Users/wadewest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peppercorn/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:505:in `on_parse_error'
    /Users/wadewest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peppercorn/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
    /Users/wadewest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peppercorn/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
    /Users/wadewest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peppercorn/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:15:in `parse'
    /Users/wadewest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peppercorn/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:438:in `parse'
    /Users/wadewest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@peppercorn/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:361:in `parse_in_order'
```

Same thing happens if I try using textile.  If anyone wants to try reproduce the problem, the project is on [github](https://github.com/wadewest/peppercorn/tree/markdown).  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're just confused about the `yard` options. The help says this:

```
$ yard --help doc
Usage: yard doc [options] [source_files [- extra_files]]
(if a list of source files is omitted, 
  {lib,app}/**/*.rb ext/**/*.c is used.)

Example: yardoc -o documentation/ - FAQ LICENSE
  The above example outputs documentation for files in
  lib/**/*.rb to documentation/ including the extra files
  FAQ and LICENSE.
...
```

so when you say this:

```
$ yard doc -m markdown -- README.md
```

Yard will try to interpret `README.md` as a source file of some kind. Your `README.md` will be interpreted as a Ruby source file (which it isn't) and that results in a *Ruby* error like this:

```
unexpected tinteger, expecting $end
```

If you edit your `README.md` a bit you'll see the location of the error moving around but the error will make sense if you try to read `README.md` as a Ruby source file.

You don't need to say anything about `README.md` when running `yard` at all, `yard` will know what to do with `README.md` all by itself.

Comment: ty mu, apparently I didn't read the very top of the help. `yard doc - README.md` did the trick.